# Alt tag font size

Tags: html, email, font-size, alt

Hey I'm currently building an email, I've got my logo

```
<img src="head/email-concept1_04.gif" width="172" height="61" border="0" alt="Test" title="Test" style="display:block; color:#ffffff !important;" />
```

I have have tried to make the `alt` tag's font size bigger but it doesn't seem to work.

```
<img src="head/email-concept1_04.gif" width="172" height="61" border="0" alt="Test" title="Test" style="display:block; color:#ffffff !important; font-weight:bold !important; font-size:36px !important;" />
```

I've seen it applied to emails I have received, e.g. from Pizza Express, just can't figure out how they've done it.

Comment: I imagine they use an `<h1>` with a `background-image`.

Comment: Perhaps look at the html source of an email that has the effect your desire? See how that email accomplished what you want to do and learn from it.

Comment: your code should work - http://jsfiddle.net/ntaMS/  what client are you testing in?

Comment: Hey Zoltan, it seems to work when testing in Firefox but when checking IE and Chrome does not show.

Comment: Solved the issue with the below code, one thing to note is that the font size can't be too big!

    <a href="http://www.paulsmith.co.uk/shop/home/" style="text-decoration:underline;color:#ffffff" target="_blank"><font style="font:18px Verdana,Helvetica,sans-serif;color:#ffffff"><img src="head/email-concept1_04.gif" width="172" height="61" border="0" alt="Paul Smith" style="display:block"></font></a>

Answer (score 6):

You can do this simply putting the image tag in a container and implementing font style for that particular container. Example:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            #font {
                width:400px;
                height:400px;
                margin:0 auto;
                font-size:16px;
                font-weight:bold;
                color:#ff0000;
                text-align:center;

            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="font">
            <img src="" alt="Customized Font" />
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```